# Google Glass (Not installed)

Tags: android-studio, google-glass, google-gdk

I am new to Android Studio and google-Glass.

I am trying to create a knew project that will use google-glass but my problem is when I have to Check/select glass it is Disabled and I do not know how to fix this problem.

See the Image below.

[image]

and here is my SDK that shows that i have installed APK 19.

[image]

and with the Image below it shows that the glass does appear on Android Studio

[image]

can anyone please help me if the is something wrong that i am doing.

will appreciate your Help.

Comment: Are you sure that you're showing the correct SDK manager? Did you open it from Android Studio?

Comment: Yes i did it from the same Android Studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, I needed to make sure I also installed the latest Android SDK Tools, Android SDK Platform-tools, and Android SDK Build-tools. Lastly, also install Android SDK Build-tools rev. 20. All four of these are under "Tools" in the SDK Manager.

Downloading the above allowed me to create a new Glass project.

Also try:
Go to File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location. Make sure it is the correct SDK directory.

Comment: Thank you my problem was that my Android Studio was using its own SDK that it installed the time i was installing Studio. so had to download those things you mention and now its working.

Comment: I am trying to start developing an application for google glass as my final year project but am having the same issues. I have installed the packages that you have mentioned but it still isnt working

Comment: In case anyone's having this issue, you may also have to downgrade your version of Android Studio. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32162279/android-studio-1-3-1-and-google-glass-create-new-project-target-android-dev

Answer (score 0):

I installed the GDK with version 1.3.2 but, even checking the correct path of the SDK and GDK, the initial wizard for starting a new project didn't recognize it (still was saying "Glass (not installed)").

I had then to uninstall the current version of Android Studio and delete the SDK; I installed version 1.1 and downloaded again the SDK and GDK and then it works.